# Displays don't sleep when the computer is idle under gnome3

Tags: gnome, display, lock-screen, screensaver

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1, with Gnome3 desktop. I have **Screen Blank Delay** set to 15 minutes in `Settings > Privacy > Screen Lock`, but this does nothing. When my computer is idle for longer than 15 minutes, the desktop stays on the screen without going to sleep. If I lock the screen manually, it also does not put the displays to sleep on its own. I can leave my computer idle for days and my displays will stay on unless I push the power button on each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I was misinformed, and thought Ubuntu was running on `Gnome3` by default now, however, this is incorrect. Ubuntu seems to run `lightdm`, which the screensaver and screen sleep do not work through it. I was able to solve the issue by running:

```bsh
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

and selecting the `gdm3` option from the list. A couple warnings/errors wrote to the console but after rebooting I logged in and was able to test and confirm that my displays slept according to the settings in `Settings > Privacy > Screen Lock`.